# DB2 SQL - Difference (minus) of CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, db2, difference, case-when

I am trying to do the difference between 2 case when in a DB2 environment as follow:

```
select DISTINCT 
TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER, 
TLORDER.XCHARGES,
TLORDER.CHARGES,
TLORDER.DISTANCE, 
TLORDER.CREATED_TIME,
TLORDER.DESTCITY,
(CASE WHEN ODRSTAT.STATUS = '5ARRCONS' THEN MAX(ORDSTAT.CHANGED)
END -
CASE WHEN ODRSTAT.STATUS = 'PICKD' THEN MIN(ODRSTAT.CHANGED)
END) AS DETENTION
FROM ODRSTAT
LEFT JOIN TLORDER ON ODRSTAT.ORDER_ID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
```

I tried a few variation of this concept using the various online ressources and found many answers for sums but not for difference using the same columns.

The goal is to substract the oldest date (in col. CHANGED) if status in Col. Status is 'pickd' from the newest date (in the same col CHANGED) if the status in Col. STATUS is '5arrcons'

Consider the following dataset:

```
Key ORDER_ID    STATUS      CHANGED
1   10          5ARRCONS    12/10/2017
2   10          OTHER       12/10/2017
3   10          PICKD       12/5/2017
4   10          OTHER       12/3/2017
5   10          PICKD       12/1/2017
```

In this case the wanted result from the CASE statement would be
MAX = 12/10/2017
Min = 12/1/2017

so (12/10/2017 - 12/1/2017) equals 9
9 is what I would want in what is returned

Any and all help will be appreciated.
thank you for your time

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your non-working SQL code doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly you want want.  But, this may be what you want:

```
SELECT o.BILL_NUMBER, o.XCHARGES, o.CHARGES, o.DISTANCE, o.CREATED_TIME, o.DESTCITY,
       (MAX(CASE WHEN os.STATUS = '5ARRCONS' THEN os.CHANGED END) -
        MIN(CASE WHEN os.STATUS = 'PICKD' THEN os.CHANGED END)
       ) AS DETENTION
FROM ODRSTAT os JOIN
     TLORDER o
     ON os.ORDER_ID = o.DETAIL_LINE_ID
GROUP BY o.BILL_NUMBER, o.XCHARGES, o.CHARGES, o.DISTANCE, o.CREATED_TIME, o.DESTCITY;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, works like a charm! I still edited my question for those who might ned something similar. Have a great day!